# How do I customize a table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I know there's a way to change the background color of a table, but is there a way to change the text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who are looking for custom cells:

http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

In your DataSource for the table there is a method that returns the table cells for the table. In effect the method returns a view that you can customize.

Check out:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```